# Find the element in a std::set in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, set

What would be the key in case of Objects being inserted into std::set? As for the following example, I am inserting objects of class Classcomp into the std::set. However, I want to find whether an object of Classcomp with a particular 'id = 1' exists in the std::set or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Classcomp {
  int val = 0;
  int id = 0; ///ID for the object
  bool operator() (const Classcomp& lhs, const Classcomp& rhs) const
  {return lhs.val<rhs.val;}
};

int main ()
{

  Classcomp c1,c2,c3,c4;
  c1.val = 92;c1.id = 2;
  c2.val = 94;c2.id = 3;
  c3.val = 10;c3.id = 1;

  std::set<Classcomp,Classcomp> fifth;                 // class as Compare

    fifth.insert(c1);fifth.insert(c2);fifth.insert(c3);

    for (auto x: fifth) {std::cout << x.id << "  " << x.val << std::endl;} 

    if (fifth.find()) {std::cout << "Got it";} //What should I pass as arguments to fifth.find()?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since your class does not have an `id` member the answer is easy.  There are no objects with that `id` in the set.

Comment: @NathanOliver: My bad, forgot to mention. The attribute 'key' is the ID that I am referring to.

Comment: Please do not(!)  mix data and the compare predicate (`bool Classcomp::operator()` and `std::set<Classcomp,Classcomp>` are bad)

Comment: @Jarod42 : Yup, fixed it.

Comment: Side note: `bool operator < (const Classcomp& lhs, const Classcomp& rhs) const ` would be fine for a `std::set<Classcomp>`.

Answer (score 4):

Sets is different from the map by exactly the fact that *values* of objects inside the set are their *keys*. If you need to separate a key from the value, you need a key-value container, such as `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

**Clarification** 
I am not talking about the option of simply iterating over all objects in the set and checking every object to have specified key - which is easily done with `std::find`. If that's what you want, please clarify.

Comment: Well, indeed he can define the `operator==` for his class or use a different class than `equal_to` to compare the objects.

Comment: @skypjack : That would lead to a linear complexity. Though, what you said is doable. I guess, I need to have unordered_map as being mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry, I was considering the unordered one.

Answer (score 1):

As your class is sorted by field `val` you have following options:

- iterate over all elements and find one with particular id by `std::find` or `std::find_if`
- create another container and sort there by id (maybe using std::share_ptr to avoid duplicates)
- use `boost::multiindex` and create index by `val` as well as `id`